# Order Coredata Sub-entity

Tags: arrays, core-data, tableview

My entities called `Score` contains entites called `Messages`. It's a `one-to-many` relationship, we can have many `Messages` for a single `Score`.

When I'm fetching my `Score`, i can access my `Messages` objects in an NSOrderedSet, because I ticked Ordered in the `.xcdatamodel` file.

They're just not ordered properly and I'd like to know if that can be fixed.

I'm displaying them in a tableview from an array built like this

```
//_score exists and is set properly.

someArray = array-alloc-init;

for (Message *msg in _score.messages)
{
    //Do my stuff because objects need remodeling in that view
    //
    [someArray addObject:msg];
}

[tableview reloadData];  //the tableview uses someArray
```

everything works like a charm except it's just not in the right order.

Where (if possible) can I tell the model to order by "CreationDate" for example. The "Ordered" tickbox seems to order it in a way that doesn't work.

Comment: What order did you set the items in? Do you really want an ordered set or a fetch with sort?

Comment: Well i'm not fetching the Type2 so how could I sort them? I'm fetching the type1 objects, and access type2 by just using type1.type2

Edit: i'll replace those silly type1 & 2 names it's confusing.

Comment: So yeah, i'm not fetching any message, i'm just fetching my scores, and for them I use a sort descriptor in the fetch. Then in each score when I want to display the messages, i use score.messages   and I have them, they're "already" fetched. Which is cool, but I have to re-sort that specific set myself if I want them in order. Is there a way I can have them fetched with a specific sort descriptor even though they're a sub-entity of my Score entity?

Comment: They aren't fetched, they are accessed if you will. They are in the order you originally saved them in. So really yhey should be ordered when you populate the relationship.

Comment: I'm looking into that, indeed I was first inserting them in a "random" order (whichever order the server fetched it).
If it's that I invite you to post this as an answer for future reference and also reputation points for yourself ^^ (Not that you seem to actually need it)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The ordered set is in whatever order you originally populated the relationship (either in one go or as items were added to the end of the relationship).

So, if you can guarantee that you can add them in order or you write some code to insert into the relationship in the correct place then you can continue with your current code.

Alternatively, you can create a fetch request that uses the relationship 'backwards' to find `Message`s for a specified `Score` and sorts them appropriately. The main benefit here is that you can decide to change the sort order if you want to on-the-fly, you can specify multiple sort orderings (allowing the user to change if they want) and you can explicitly set the fetch batch size (which can help if you have lots of messages).

Comment: Thanks for the answer and the extra info. Didn't think of letting the user chose which order he wants on his messages. :)